# Laravel 4 - one migrations in workbench can be rolled back, while others cannot

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have two types of workbench migrations: creating regular tables and creating pivot tables for Many-to-Many relationships.

Sample of regular migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
        Schema::create('users', function(\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();

            $table->string('login')->unique();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->boolean('active')->default(true);

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}

}
```

Above migration can be rolled back

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePivotRoleUser extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
        Schema::create('role_user', function(\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint $table)
        {   
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

            $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
}

}
```

While this cannot, because it gives

> "Class 'CreatePivotPermissionRole' not found"

error.

How to fix it?

Comment: I see no `CreatePivotPermissionRole` defined either. Have you tried running `composer dump-auto` to nudge the class loader?

Comment: @Iserni I gave random sample, the same error is with `CreatePivotRoleUser`. Yes, I tried nudging autoloader. And migrating works, only rollback fails.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. 
If CreatePivotPermissionRole is not found, it means it had been deleted before. Check the content of all your down() methods, there must be something wrong there.